# Characters With Interchangeable Skills

Tags: c#, unity

I am using unity and I would like to create characters that have interchangeable spells. As an example it would be something like Pokemon that can attain different skills as they level up and the user can change out skills for new ones. Would this be a good place for inheritance? Should I make a parent class that inherited by all of the other characters? Would this be the best approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Would this be a good place for inheritance?

No, this is a good place for composition, see the Strategy pattern for more details.

First of all, define an interface for your skills. Each character will have an instance of a class that implements that interface as a member. This ensures that you can switch between skills at runtime with ease. A simplistic example would look like this:

```
interface ISkill
{
      void Execute(Character character);
}

class HealingSkill : ISkill
{
      public void Execute(Character character)
      {
          character.Health += 10;
      }
}

class Character
{
       public int Health { get; set; }
       private ISkill _activeSkill;

       public void ChangeSkill(ISkill newSkill)
       {
           _activeSkill = newSkill;
       }

       public void UseSkill()
       {
           if (_activeSkill != null)
           {
               _activeSkill.Execute(this);
           }
       }
}

//In-game
var myChar = new Character();
myChar.ChangeSkill(new HealingSkill());
myChar.UseSkill();
```

Comment: What does this offer over using something like a delegate function?

Comment: ISkill implementers may have a state of their own. With delegates you'd have to track that state separately for each delegate requiring it.

Comment: Nice reference to the Strategy pattern. Rule of thumb: 'is a' relationship -> inheritance (e.g. a dog is a mammal), 'has a' -> composition (e.g. a plane has seats).